# Stretch a line along width in react-native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am showing a modal in my app where I want to show a line between the message and the close button. I want to know how can I stretch a line across the width of the `View` . Below is a sample component on rnplay which displays the problem. It shows a line where I have explicitly set the `width` to `100`. I wanted to know if there is a way to do it automatically using some flex-box property.

https://rnplay.org/apps/LeYqmQ

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<View style={{flex: 1, height: 3, alignItems: 'stretch', width: 100, backgroundColor: '#dddddd'}}/>
```

with

```
<View style={{height: 3, alignSelf: 'stretch', backgroundColor: '#dddddd'}}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. If I were to understand why `flex: 1` didn't work, I guess it was because the width provided to the `View` by its parent was just that much due to which it couldn't only expand to that small area and giving `alignSelf: stretch` caused it to stretch to the full width. Or is there some other explanation.